# Servlet mapping in jetty server

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, jetty

I am trying to edit a website:

- server : Jetty
- framework : spring
- index.html page is in ./web/

From this, mapping to webpages in ./web/WEB_INF/template using Servlet. We would like to add one more module in this index.html.. requests help on Servlet mapping.

Comment: i dont know how to do servelet mapping properly. i tried editing the web.xml and the controller servelet class.. but zero success.. so may be someone could provide me with some suggestions or useful links.. thank u..

Comment: Where do you want to add a "module"? I don't know what you mean by adding a module into index.html. If you just want to add a new servlet and its mapping, Bozho has answered that question for you. What exactly do you want to do? Are you looking for a way to modify your index.html? Typically, you use MVC pattern with Spring web application. Modifying controller will mostly change the underlyinh model. If you want to make change to index.html page on the web browser, you need to look into the view of the controller you are looking at.

Comment: there are already 3 modules- begin connection,admin area,member area in index.html  i want to add an extra module and map it to a webpage in                                                                /WEB-INF/template.                                                             <a href="session/login.html" >Begin Internet Connection</a>        <a href="member/login.html">Member Area</a>
<a href="admin-login.html">Administrator Area</a>

Comment: i cant understand how the mapping is done,session and member are servlets and member-login.html and session-login.html are the web pages in /WEB-INF/template.these servlets uses FreeMarkerViewResolver and BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.

Comment: I found this site to be the most useful http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html

Comment: What you are looking for isn't a servlet mapping but it's how Spring handle mapping works.

Answer (score 2):

A servlet is mapped in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.myclass.etcetera.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It is thus accessible through `http://localhost:8080/app/MyServlet`

If you are using the latest version of the servlet API (3.0), you can map it using the `@WebServlet` annotation on the servlet itself (and of course, specify there the url-pattern on which the servlet will respond)